# Raspberry Pi 4 VNC Remote Connection Desktop Error

Tags: vnc

### Surroundings

- Raspberry Pi system: [Raspbian Buster with desktop](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt)
- Direct connection using fiber

### Problem

VNC connection remote desktop error: **cannot currently show the desktop**, I have enabled VNC and boot desktop automatic login option when booting, but still can't connect to the desktop, what other options do I need to set?

Attached: SSH everything is normal

[image: error message]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in addition to the above two operations must also set the resolution, the specific location in Advanced Options > Resolution, select the appropriate resolution.

1. [image: first step]
2. [image: Second step]
3. [image: third step]

Comment: This is not working for me. :(

Comment: not working for me, raspbian lite version

Answer (score 4):

I installed on the smart card the Debian `VERSION="10 (buster)"`. There is no Display connected to the Raspberry. I'm connected it only through it's Ethernet (UTP-cable), and the wifi module is disabled. I edited as sudo the `/boot/config.txt` file to disabble the wifi loading on boot.

```
# wifi off / dissable
# change on 10-08-2019
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
```

I gave a try to connect on it with VNC from another Rpi, and I got the same Message: 
`Cannot currently show the desktop`

I logged through ssh on that computer and started the desktop:

```
ssh user@ipadress
# where the user is
echo $USER
# where the ipadress is
ip a | grep -o "[1-9].*/24" | sed 's/\/.*//g'
```

after I logged in into that remote computer

```
sudo startx
```

And it worked!

[image: The remote desktop voila!]

Comment: Most of this is irrelevant! Obviously, if you don't have a desktop, VNC can't display it.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the GL Experimental Desktop - I also then set the screen resolution in raspi-config. I tried everything else and this was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me also - without disabling the GL desktop it was stuck in a low-res 4:3 mode

Answer (score 0):

Your pi seems not running a graphical desktop. Since remote access with SSH is working, an alternative solution is to create a **virtual desktop** using the VNC Server and connect to it afterwards.

The raspberrypi.org provides a [doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) for such connection: with SSH, run `vncserver` and make note of the IP address/display number. Then you can use it for the VNC connection.

With my headless pi as an example:[image]

The IP address/display number for the VNC connection is in the Connectivity section. BTW I hide the Security information.